# Iterate through Spark column of type Array[DateType] and see if there are two consecutive days in the array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame, which consists of 2 columns. The first one is `ID`, the second one is array of several dates associated with that `ID`.

I need to iterate through the column, which contains dates and see if there are 2 consecutive days in that array.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                  id|                date|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|1003                |[2018-02-12, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-04, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-05, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-02, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-28, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-07, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-13, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-21, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-15, 2018...|
|1003                |[2018-02-15, 2018...|
+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Hi @tatevik, take a look at ``lag`` and windowing functions, that's all you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Spark >=2.4, you can do that with [Higher-Order Functions](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/apache-spark-2.4-functions.html) on arrays. Here is an example:

```
// example data
val df = Seq(
(1003, Array("2019-01-13", "2019-01-14", "2019-05-O3")), 
(1004, Array("2019-02-23", "2019-01-18", "2019-12-O6")), 
(1005, Array("2019-03-10", "2019-06-23", "2019-06-24")), 
(1006, Array("2019-04-11", "2019-04-18", "2019-14-19"))
).toDF("id","date")

// first we sort the dates in the array column
val sortedDatesDf = df.select(col("id"), array_sort(col("date")).alias("dates"))

// we apply transform, and exists function on the sorted array of dates
sortedDatesDf.withColumn("consecutive_dates", exists(transform(col("dates"), 
(x, i) => lit(date_add(x, lit(1)) === col("dates")(i+1))), x => x)
).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------+
|id  |dates                               |consecutive_dates|
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------+
|1003|[2019-01-13, 2019-01-14, 2019-05-O3]|true             |
|1004|[2019-01-18, 2019-02-23, 2019-12-O6]|null             |
|1005|[2019-03-10, 2019-06-23, 2019-06-24]|true             |
|1006|[2019-04-11, 2019-04-18, 2019-14-19]|null             |
+----+------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

**How does it work?**

- First, we sort the array of dates so that we could compare 2 consecutive values. The `array_sort` function will sort the input array in ascending order.
- The `transform` function takes the sorted array and a lambda function : `(x, i) => Boolean`. Where `x` the actual value and `i` its index in the array. So, to know if two dates are consecutive we add one day to `x` and check if it's equal to the next date in the array (index `i+1`).
- Finally, we check if we have at least one value `true` in the transformed array (which means there are at least 2 dates consecutive) using `exists` function and lambda function `x => Boolean`, as the values are of type Boolean, we just need `x => x`.

**How to do it without Hight-Order Functions?**

If you can not use the above solution, you can use other solutions as :

- Create UDF function that takes a list of dates and returns boolean if it contains two consecutive dates and then use it with your DF : `df.withColumn("consecutive_dates", containsConsecurtiveDates(col("date")))`.
- Another solution would be to explode the `date` column and then use some SQL Window functions (`lag`, `row_number`,..) to detect IDs that have consecutive dates, and finally, groupBy you result by ID.